# Custom control: Button Released event does not fire when swiping away

Tags: android, events, button, xamarin.forms, custom-controls

I created a custom control that uses a button with a long-press action. When the button gets `Pressed` an action starts. When the button is `Released` the action stops. The problem is that once the button is `Pressed` the user can choose to swipe his finger away from the button. The `Released` event won't fire when this happens and the action that was triggered by the `Pressed` event keeps running indefinitely.

This is my XAML code of the custom control:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<ContentView
    x:Class="TestProject.NumericUpDown"
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    x:Name="this">

    <ContentView.Content>
        <Button
            x:Name="TestButton"
            Grid.Row="0"
            Grid.Column="0"
            Pressed="TestButton_Pressed"
            Released="TestButton_Released"
            Text="Test" />
    </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

In the codebehind I have these methods to test the events:

```
private void TestButton_Pressed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Pressed");
}

private void TestButton_Released(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Released");
}
```

This is my page that uses the user control:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage
    x:Class="ButtonTest.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:ButtonTest"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ButtonTest">

    <ScrollView>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
            <local:TestControl />
        </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</ContentPage>
```

I have read that a press and release action can change halfway because it becomes a swipe action. But how do I detect this so I can cancel the action I started by the `Pressed` event?

**Update**: This issue seems to be version related. My project works on the latest Xamarin version which is 4.3. Visual Studio 2019 defaults to Xamarin 3.4 which does not have this issue! If you want to test this issue use Xamarin 3.6 or higher.

**Update 2**: I have added the page XAML code. This includes a ScrollView that seems to be the source of the problem. A StackLayout does not have this problem.

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't quite follow you by  the words : `I have read that a press and release action can change halfway because it becomes a swipe action. But how do I detect this so I can cancel the action I started by the Pressed event?`

Comment: @Jessie Assume that I have a button and I would touch the button without releasing it. If I move my finger upward after that I start touching it the Android system starts scrolling the page instead of touching the button. So the `Pressed` event from the button gets cancelled or something. That does not trigger a `Released` event.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't quite follow you.How did you start scrolling the page? Does this page have a scrolling function?

Comment: The page does not have to have a scrolling function. In this case, it has not. I just "swipe" my finger away from the button after I started touching it.

Comment: Can you please add some more code, like where you use it. I tried to reproduce it and the release event is always called on my side.

Comment: i agree with @alexgavru, i can also see the release event being fired in all cases. You should elaborate on the steps to reproduce the issue, and maybe also tell us your system configuration.

Comment: @alexgavru It seems that this is a Xamarin version related issue. I updated my question. Could you please test this again on Xamarin 4.0 or higher?

Comment: @Martin I tested with Xamarin 4.2.0.709249 and upgraded to the latest 4.3.0.991211. Same results, released is called no matter how I swipe or do when tapping the button. Where do you use this control? Add some more code please.

Comment: @alexgavru I have added the code and in my own tests the `ScrollView` seems to be the problem. That should narrow it down.

Comment: Sorry to interrupt, the nuget upgrade is designed to solve the problem of the previous version. If the latest version is ok, why bother with the problem of the previous version.

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT It is the other way around. The problem is related to the latest version. The previous version does not have this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. That's what I came to:

```
public class CustomButtonRenderer : ButtonRenderer
    {
        public CustomButtonRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Button> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control != null && e.NewElement != null)
            {
                Control.Touch += OnTouch;
            }
        }

        private void OnTouch(object sender, TouchEventArgs args)
        {
            var buttonController = (IButtonController)Element;
            if (buttonController == null)
                return;

            var x = (int) args.Event.GetX();
            var y = (int) args.Event.GetY();

            if (!TouchInsideControl(x, y))
            {
                buttonController.SendReleased();
            }
            else if (args.Event.Action  == MotionEventActions.Down)
            {
                buttonController.SendPressed();
            }
            else if (args.Event.Action == MotionEventActions.Up)
            {
                buttonController.SendReleased();
                buttonController.SendClicked();    
            }
        }

        private bool TouchInsideControl(int x, int y)
        {
            return x <= Control.Right && x >= Control.Left && y <= Control.Bottom && y >= Control.Top;
        }
    }
```